# vbscript to launch internet explorer, navigate to URL and click button

Tags: internet-explorer, button, vbscript, click

I have been scraping the Internet for some solution to this problem with no success. I need to use vbscript to launch a URL within Internet Explorer and click a button. The challenge that I am having is that the button has no id or name. It only has a specified type and value. I have tried different methods with no success. I would love some help if you can.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getElementsByTagName` to find all of the button elements (or input elements) in the page and then look at the `name` property to see if it is the one you want.

Comment: Ah. Should have thought of that. I will give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: sorry. Having trouble using this. Can you provide an example? Keep getting object required no matter how I slice it.

Comment: Can you post a reduced example with HTML and VBscript?

Answer (score 1):

Try this with groovy:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.*;

Scriptom.inApartment
{
  def ie = new ActiveXObject('InternetExplorer.Application')

  ie.Visible = true
  ie.AddressBar = true

  ie.Navigate("http://glaforge.free.fr/weblog")
}
```

This code is from http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/scriptom/scriptom-all-assembly/1.6.0/scriptom-all-assembly-1.6.0.zip